# Is there any Mega menu module?

Tags: theming, navigation

I am building a web site using drupal 8 and I want add a mega menu (3 columns menu with images) to the site.

Previously I have used [TB Mega menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu), but it does not support Drupal 8. Is there any mega menu module that supports Drupal 8, or is there a work-around which allows to install TB Mega menu on Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Ultimenu module. It has Drupal 8 version too and it's stable.

https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimenu

> Ultimenu is the UltimatelyDeadSimple™ megamenu ever with dynamic
>   region creation.
>
> The module manages the toggle of Ultimenu blocks, regions, and a skins
>   library, while leaving the management of block, menu and regions to
>   Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

It Here and it work. https://www.drupal.org/project/we_megamenu is Drupal 8 Mega menu